# VBA Paste based on Row, Column number

Tags: excel, paste

I am trying to write macro which paste based on row and column numbers in another sheet.
Trying to change K44 to needed column, row. 
Anyone know how to write that it will understand rows, columns values?

[image: Column, Row numbers]

```
Sub Button4_Click()
'
' Button4_Click Macro

Range("B38:O40").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("K44").Select  (need adjust this range by specific column, number)
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=True
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: One option would be: `Cells(row, column).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=True`, where row and column are the values from your worksheet.
You don't need to select ranges in this case. That just slows down massively.

Comment: Thanks, but I am struggling to update code, could you add full? Should I use Cells(A43, B43)? It looks too simple :)

Comment: I got that needed, thanks!!

Comment: Prextor, maybe You know hot to paste values to another sheet by that column, row number?

Comment: In general, within the environment of Excel there is a hierarchy of objects, if want so. These could be workbook, worksheet... When referring to a cell in the active worksheet (e.g. named "Sheet1") you could also write `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,1)` or simply `Cells(1,1)`. Therefore, referring to a non-active sheet you want to write `Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1,1)`. See also MSDN documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer

Check = sheet.Range("A:XFD").Find(what:="prashant", lookat:=xlWhole).Address

right(left(chk,2),1)